# My iphone app(with swift code) cannot run in mobile with IOS 11.2.5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have developed an app with Xcode 9.2 with Deployment Target 11.2. This app is working fine in Simulator. But when I have update my mobile in IOS 11.2.5 its not opening. I am a newbie in IOS development. Please help me with any suggestion or any idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you are running the App from within Xcode on a tethered phone, can you post the Console Log output you get when you try to run it?

Comment: Thnx for reply. Its only showing white pages in mobile and in xcode showing Thread 1: signal SIGBRT error

Comment: Application are crashed. It may be coz of you are using some apple API that requred to set Privacy- at pList.

Comment: But its running successfully in simulator and also it was working fine in my OLD ios version. But its causing this issue after updating into IOS 11.2.5

Comment: Thnx but its solved by making CLEAR and BUILD the Apps again